# write a python regex to match multiple urls in a html source page using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am working on web scraping using beautifulsoup and trying to get links in a html page for given list of urls.

suppose if i want to get facebook and twitter links in a page, I tried

```
urls_list = ['www.facebook.com','www.apps.facebook.com', 'www.twitter.com']
reg = re.compile(i for i in urls_list)
print soup('a',{'href':reg})
```

and

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source)
reg = re.compile(r"(http|https)://(www.[apps.]facebook|twitter).com/\w+")
print soup('a',{'href':reg})
```

above code is not working and retrieving all urls in a page. please bear with my little knowledge in regex and python

Answer (score 1):

You need to produce a valid regular expression:

```
reg = re.compile(r"^https?://www\.(apps\.)?(facebook|twitter)\.com/[\w-]+")
```

Quick demo:

```
>>> reg = re.compile(r"^https?://www\.(apps\.)?(facebook|twitter)\.com/[\w-]+")
>>> reg.search('https://www.apps.facebook.com/hello_world')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x105fe39b0>
>>> reg.search('http://www.facebook.com/hello_world')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x105fe3918>
>>> reg.search('http://www.twitter.com/hello_world')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x105fe39b0>
>>> reg.search('http://www.twitters.com/')
>>> reg.search('http://www.twitter.com/')
>>> reg.search('http://twitter.com/hello')
```

The syntax `[...]` creates a character class; anything within that class matches; `[apps.]` is the same as `[aps.]` in that it'll match either an `a`, a `p`, an `s` or a `.` dot. Outside of character classes, `.` matches *any* character.

Comment: `(http|https)` == `https?`

Comment: @thg435: I missed that one because I was fixing the more glaring errors. :-)

Comment: thanks to you both.. Can you help me a little more.. I need to accept that last string also but only for one domain not for second domain. i.e.,'http://twitter.com/hello' not for 'http://facebook.com/hello'.

Comment: @user2695817: You mean like `r'^https?://www\.(apps\.)?(facebook\.com/|twitter\.com/[\w-]+)$'`?

Comment: @user2695817: That matches `http://www.facebook.com/` but not `http://www.facebook.com/hello`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: No no sorry for confusion I want to have www only for facebook, for twitter it is optional(just like the one you mentioned in last line of example)

Comment: `r'^https?://(www\.(apps\.)?facebook\.com/|(www\.)?twitter\.com/[\w-]+)$'` makes `www.` required for facebook, optional for twitter, and makes the `apps.` element optional for facebook. Perhaps it is time you looked at the [Python regex howto](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html)?

Comment: Thanks. I know its simple question but got some errors and wasted some time so asking for guidance thanks. The real query comes like this type of urls are go on increasing.

Comment: @user2695817: Why not filter on the urls *after* searching? Perhaps using a regular expression to filter them is not the way to go here.